# Four subfloats separated by vertical and horizontal lines

Tags: subfloats

I am using the following code to insert four subfloats:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
% 
\newcommand{\rulesep}{\unskip\ \vrule\ }
% 
\begin{document}
% 
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centerlast}
  \begin{subfigure}{.44\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=6.5cm,height=9.5cm]{example-image-duck}
     \caption[Short caption]{Isosurface corresponding to $H_{m}(x)$.}
    \label{subfig1a}
  \end{subfigure} 
  \hfill
  \rulesep
  \begin{subfigure}{.44\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=6.5cm,height=9.5cm]{example-image-duck}
    \caption[caption]{Isosurface corresponding to $H_{m}(x).$}
    \label{subfig1b}
  \end{subfigure}
     \vspace{0.6cm}
  \hrule
   \vspace{0.6cm}\par
     \captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centerlast}
  \begin{subfigure}{.44\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=6.5cm,height=9.5cm]{example-image-duck}
     \caption[Short caption]{Isosurface corresponding to $H_{m}(x)$.}
    \label{subfig1a}
  \end{subfigure} 
  \hfill
  \rulesep
  \begin{subfigure}{.44\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=6.5cm,height=9.5cm]{example-image-duck}
    \caption[caption]{Isosurface corresponding to $H_{m}(x).$}
    \label{subfig1b}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Caption of Figure 1.}
\end{figure}
% 
\end{document}
```

The output of which is:

[image]

I would like to have the vertical line separating the subfigures a and b and the vertical line separating the subfigures c and d, to be a continuous line. i.e.:

[image]

What changes should I make to the current code? Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `tabular`.

For such a big float, the option `[H]` is decidedly out of place. It should *never* be used, actually.

To be honest, I'd not use the rules: they add nothing to clarity.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centerlast}

\begin{document}
% 
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} c|c @{}}
  \begin{subfigure}{.44\columnwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=6.5cm,height=9.5cm]{example-image-duck}
     \caption[Short caption]{Isosurface corresponding to $H_{m}(x)$.}
    \label{subfig1a}
  \end{subfigure}
&
  \begin{subfigure}{.44\columnwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=6.5cm,height=9.5cm]{example-image-duck}
    \caption[caption]{Isosurface corresponding to $H_{m}(x).$}
    \label{subfig1b}
  \end{subfigure}
\\
& \\
\hline
& \\
  \begin{subfigure}{.44\columnwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=6.5cm,height=9.5cm]{example-image-duck}
     \caption[Short caption]{Isosurface corresponding to $H_{m}(x)$.}
    \label{subfig1a}
  \end{subfigure} 
&
  \begin{subfigure}{.44\columnwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=6.5cm,height=9.5cm]{example-image-duck}
    \caption[caption]{Isosurface corresponding to $H_{m}(x).$}
    \label{subfig1b}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{tabular}

\caption{Caption of Figure 1.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]